# How to translate "Minute Stepping" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

This is related to working with time, as in hours and selecting minutes.

As we know, minute stepping can be a custom setting, as in 5's, 10's, 20's, and so forth. How can I properly translate that into Brazilian Portuguese?

It doesn't have to be in a sentence, due to the fact that it can be a standalone option, such as in my case, "Select Minute Stepping". But we can use that in a sentence in the same way. "Please choose the appropriate minute stepping according to your desire".

Comment: "minute stepping: 5" means 21:00 -> 21:05 -> 21:10 -> 21:15 and so on?

Comment: Yeah, that's how we would use it. As in.. minute stepping of 20.  It would be 1:20, 1:40 and 2:00pm. @Bruno, It doesn't have to be in a sentence due to fact that it can be a standalone option such as in my case. "Select Minute Stepping". But we can use that in a sentence in the same way. "Please choose the appropriate minute stepping according to your desire:"

Comment: @Hugo I see you rejected my edit. It would be nice of you to include, in some form, what you said in your latest comment. You rejected giving the reason that "Select Minute Stepping" was just a sample you gave. However in you comment you said.. `it can be a standalone option such as in my case. "Select Minute Stepping"`. Meaning that **you want** to translate "Select minute stepping"

Comment: I couldn't see @BrunoCosta's edit, but it is bugging me that your comment is both longer and more detailed than the answer itself, Hugo. What I think he meant is that it would be nice if you could provide a few examples where our answers would be required to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation precedents seem to favor the word `incremento`:

> [Valor válido : Um número de três dígitos. Cada unidade representa um **incremento de 5 minutos**. Exemplo: "003" é igual a 15 minutos.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br//SSDF7K_9.0.0/com.ibm.help.spe_admn.doc/Swift/r_SWIFTOutbnd_Bulk_EnvFields_Adv.html)

That being said, I like the term `precisão, em minutos` better. It is not unheard of:

[image]
[<sub>source</sub>](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Qjry-QmO3wkC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22precis%C3%A3o%20de%201%20minuto%22&source=bl&ots=sdrfZ-XodU&sig=fksRnSITJwKuvCIU_ZPNhvM-AK4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG8r3PlfDRAhWHvJAKHbrPBdEQ6AEIIzAD#v=onepage&q=%22precis%C3%A3o%20de%201%20minuto%22&f=false)

In an example, it would be something like

> Selecione a precisão, em minutos

If the minutes UI element is visible, you can drop `em minutos`, since it's implied:

```
Precisão:    1 minuto
             2 minutos
             5 minutos
             10 minutos
```

Comment: Props for "incremento" however I am not totally sure that "precisão" would fit here. When you use "precisão" you are not really conveying that the action occurs periodically.

Comment: @BrunoCosta I didn't interpret as a periodic action, but rather as the jump (or _step_) between one option and the next one available. I'm just as unsure as  you are, though.

Answer (score 2):

The translation should be **Incremento** ou

**Acréscimo/Decréscimo** in case of representation of positive (**Acréscimo**) and negative (**Decréscimo**) step.

Answer (score 1):

In general the expression "intervalo de tempo" can be used to convey a time interval. This expression can be used for any time unit: seconds, minutes, hours, days, ...

> Escolha o intervalo de tempo (Choose the time interval)

If you want to be specific you add the time unit to the setence:

> Escolha o intervalo de tempo em minutos (Choose the time interval in minutes)

Alternatively you can also use "periodicidade", which has a similar meaning to "intervalo de tempo". However "Periocidade" conveys that something happens periodically.

> Selecione a periocidade (Select the Periodicity)

Once again if you want to be specific you add the time unit

> Selecione a periocidade em minutos (Select the Periodicity in minutes)

Alternatively you can use "A cada x minutos", however it seems this does not really fit in your particular scenario.

> A operação será realizada a cada 5 minutos (The operation will execute every 5 minutes)